# How to print task list & gantt chart from a specific date range

Tags: ms-project, gantt

I want to print the task list and the Gantt chart in a specific date range (as illustrated in the image below). How can I do it? The default print scheme wastes paper and is difficult to read. I have gone through all the print options provided in MS Project but it didn't help.

[image: print only tasklist & gant]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the **Date Selection** provided in the Print Dialog? Date selection options are highlighted in blue color in the following screenshot:

[image]

I tried it in MS Project 2007 and it worked fine. Full chart was taking 3 pages, when I used the date range then the chart got printed in 2 pages.

[image]

Comment: this is soooooo helpful. thank you. finally!

Answer (score 1):

I filter the date range in project; I have a standard project filter & view for "Six Month Horizon" which includes only those tasks that start or end in the next six months.

That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a new column for specific "Marked Tasks" is a pretty good way ahead, see :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141654

Comment: Although we can consider Microsoft link reliable (it's unlikely to have it down / deleted) would be good to explain at least a few steps directly in your answer to avoid relying on external sources on your answers. Tks